# How to get error raised from DB for wcf ria service?

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I use EF + WCF ria service fro SL app. Here is my situation:

A table update is mapped to a SP in EF. In this SP, I use RAISERROR ('My Test Message', 11,1) to produce error message for some exception.

Then capture this error by override SaveChanges:

```
  public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
        {            
            try
            {
                return base.SaveChanges(options);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 throw ex;
            }
        }
```

At client, process exception as:

```
Context.SubmitChanges(s =>
{
   try
     {
       if (s.HasError)
         {
            //......
           errs = s.Error.Message;
         }
      //....
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         //....
         errs = s.Error.Message;
      }                   
}, null);
```

when run the app locally, everything is fine, I can get the error message produced by SP like:
Submit operation failed: My Test message

but when I deploy the app to another computer, I can't the error message, the error message is something like:
Submit operation failed: Exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException' was thrown.

Looks like something related to Web Server(IIS). How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check what your CustomErrors is set to in your web.config. Also, if you override OnError in your domain service, you can set a breakpoint to see what's 'inside' the domain exception and add an error code the client can interpret (I found this helpful).